# phpで同階層にある別のphpファイルを開く方法が知りたいです。

Tags: php

現状以下の形で実装しています。

```php
<form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0 col-7" method="POST" action="Introduction1.php">
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="inputtext">
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["inputtext"])){
    $input = $_POST["inputtext"];
    if($input = "hoge1"){
         header("location: Introduction3.php");
    }else if($input = "hoge2"){
         header("location: Introduction1.php");
    }else if($input = "hoge3"){
         header("location: Introduction2.php");
    }else if($input = "hoge4"){
         header("location: Introduction4.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Searchを押したらinputtextに入れられた文字を検索。完全一致したら各自phpに飛ばす

しかし、現状これだとほかのファイルに飛びません。なぜでしょうか。

Comment: HTML部分にはbootstrapを使ってます

Comment: 少なくとも、入力されたテキストの判定部分は `if($input == "hoge1")` の様にイコール二つじゃないと比較にならないと思います。

Comment: 度々すみません、PHPでの文字列比較は `===` 演算子や `strcmp` 関数を使った方が確実そうです。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/219094

Answer (score 1):

以下の回答を参考にしてください。ヘッダーはHTML本文より前に出力する必要があります。（条件文の中の `=` を `==` 等に修正することも忘れずに。）

https://teratail.com/questions/219094

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["inputtext"])){
    $input = $_POST["inputtext"];
    if($input == "hoge1"){
         header("location: Introduction3.php");
    }else if($input == "hoge2"){
         header("location: Introduction1.php");
    }else if($input == "hoge3"){
         header("location: Introduction2.php");
    }else if($input == "hoge4"){
         header("location: Introduction4.php");
    }
}else{
?>
<form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0 col-7" method="POST" action="Introduction1.php">
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="inputtext">
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

また、単にphpの中身を表示したい場合は、`include`関数や`require`関数を使うことを検討してもよいと思います。

https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.include.php

https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.require.php